# Android Studio is very slow when editing an xml

Tags: android-studio

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8192M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true
```

A few versions ago I noticed that when editing xml Android Studio was slower than usual.

But recently I had to create many drawables and for me it was a torture, it doesn't seem normal how long it takes and the time to be able to observe the changes I make is too much.

Everything I have found on the internet about the issue has not worked. I have given Android Studio 8gb of ram to work and it doesn't make the problem better either.

Comment: check if  Android Studio is not in power saver mode: click File > Power Save Mode

Comment: @AliSheikhpour It's not in power saving mode, I've tried both and it's still slow.

Comment: try cleaning the project. Also If you are using a simulator there may be hardware resource conflicts.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I am using a physical device. I have already tried to clean and it is still slow.